# R switch between writing to a text file and the console (stdout)

Tags: r, file-io

I have an R program that generates a lot of text using writeLines, cat and print, and I would like to be able to switch the output back and forth between a text file and the console. A minimal example follows:

```
WRITE_TO_TEXT_FILE <- TRUE
TEXT_FN <- "C:/temp/test.text"

if (WRITE_TO_TEXT_FILE) {
  fileConnection <- file(TEXT_FN )
  writeLines("My text string", fileConnection)
  close(fileConnection)

} else {
  writeLines("My text string")

}
```

But this is clumsy, and I have a lot of places in which I need to edit my write statements. Is there a way in which to give stdout a file name and then just switch between files, e.g. something like

```
if (WRITE_TO_TEXT_FILE  ) {
  fileConnection <- file(TEXT_FN )

} else {
  fileConnection <- file(stdout)

}

writeLines("My text string", fileConnection)
close(fileConnection)
```

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `stdout()` as a connection for the default output. You can do something like

```
WRITE_TO_TEXT_FILE <- TRUE
TEXT_FN <- "C:/temp/test.text"

# at the start
fcon <- stdout()
if (WRITE_TO_TEXT_FILE) {
  fcon  <- file(TEXT_FN)
}


# use fcon anytime you need to write output
writeLines("My text string", fcon)


# at the very end
if (WRITE_TO_TEXT_FILE) {
  # you usually don't close stdout
  close(fcon)
}
```

Comment: Beautiful - thank you. I see that one of the errors i made was to fail to include parentheses after stdout, i.e. I tried variants of stdout, "stdout" etc. etc., but did not type stdout().

Comment: Yeah, in R it's a function that returns a connection rather an object like in other languages.

Comment: A subtle twist: As I had to write to the file from multiple locations in the program, I had to open it in append mode i.e.  `fcon  <- file(TEXT_FN, "a)`, and, in addition, to prevent it from writing to the screen as well, I had to add `sink(fcon)` immediately after defining `fcon`. At the end of the program,  I had to add `sink()` before `close(fcon)`